REST API being stateless
I hear that RESt API is stateless. This means that server application will not be able to differentiate among many calls to the same route.
I have two questions with respect to this:

Then every API call sent, must carry a valid credentials for authentication (given that the API is protected) ?
Any web application which maintains states in the client side (example: an e-commerce app), can not be implemented using RESt API ?


REST = Representational State Transfer = check original paper for answers Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures

The client side can maintain the version of state that it needs and the back end can maintain the state that it needs and they can communicate their intended modifications to state across a stateless medium. In something like an e-commerce app, the back end should never trust the clients state, it should only alow the client  to perform the changes it is authorized to.

REST is stateless because HTTP is stateless. All the information pertaining to the request should be self-contained within the request. This means that if the underlying tcp connection is broken between 2 HTTP requests the second request should get the same response as when the TCP connection was not broken.
The statelessness of HTTP / REST really only has to do with lower layers of the protocol. There's lots of 'state' otherwise in REST apis and HTTP, for example cookies, authentication, databases all are different forms of 'state'.
To answer your specific questions:

Then every API call sent, must carry a valid credentials for authentication (given that the API is protected) ?

Yes. If a previous request on the same connection was authenticated, the second request still needs to submit credentials.

Any web application which maintains states in the client side (example: an e-commerce app), can not be implemented using REST API ?

Best I can do here is 'it depends'. If you're talking about a shopping cart that's stored in a database, that kind of state is perfectly fine for a REST API.

The authoritative reference for REST is "Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures" (Roy Fielding's dissertation).

communication must be stateless in nature..., such that each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client. -- Fielding, 2000

For contrast, consider FTP, where the data returned in response to a RETR command can depend on previously sent CWD commands.
Because REST communication is stateless, we get correct results even when requests are sent to different physical servers (perhaps behind a load balancer); the server instance handling the current request doesn't need to be able to access copies of earlier requests.

Therefore:

Then every API call sent, must carry a valid credentials for authentication

Yes, exactly.

Any web application which maintains states in the client side can not be implemented using REST API ?

No - having a client that remembers which messages have been sent and which responses have been received is allowed.
Specific examples of this in HTTP are described in the specifications for status codes 204 and 205.
